# Relationship between models and filter_by errors in Python

Tags: python, filter, sqlalchemy, model, relationship

I am currently learning Python. I have an app with two classes - customer and order. I would like to display a page that shows all orders associated with one customer (many to one relationship). I believe that I have defined the relationship correctly, but I'm getting some errors.

models.py

```
from app import db, ma

class customer(db.model):
    __tablename__="customer"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(120))
    orders = relationship("order", back_populates="customer")

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<customer %r' % self.id

class order(db.Model):
    __tablename_="order"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    customer_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("customer.id"))
    content = db.Column(db.String(120))
    customer = relationship("customer")

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<order %r' % self.id`
```

routes.py

```
from app import app
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect
from app.models import *

@app.route('/orders/<customer>')
    def show_orders(name):
        orders = order.query.join(customer, customer.id==order.customer_id).filter_by(customer.name==name).all()
        return render_template('orders.html', name=name)
```

So for example, if I typed 'orders/bob_smith', this page should display all the orders made by bob_smith in the database.

But when I try to run this, I get the following error:

```
TypeError: filter_by() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given.
```

Am I doing something wrong with the models? Or am I not assigning the right variables in filter_by? Would appreciate any help!

Edit: After some advice, I made the following change to routes.py

```
@app.route('/orders/<customer>')
    def show_orders(name):
        orders = order.query.join(customer, customer.id==order.customer_id).filter_by(customer.name==customer.name).all()
        return render_template('orders.html', name=name)
```

I was able to see orders/bob_smith, but instead of showing me only bob_smith's orders, I saw all orders in the database.

orders.html

```
{{ name }} Orders
{% for order in orders %}
{{ order.customer }} # should all be bob_smith
{{ order.content }}
```

But instead, I'm seeing a list of all the orders. Am I not limiting the query sufficiently?

Answer (score 1):

Just some small updates:

```
@app.route('/orders/<customer_name>')
    def show_orders(customer_name):
        orders = order.query.join(customer, customer.id==order.customer_id).filter(customer.name==customer_name).all()
        return render_template('orders.html', orders=orders)
```

order.html will then need to have:

```
{% for order in orders %}

  {{ order.customer }}
  {{ order.content }}
  
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks, I did try that. But now the page is displaying all customers' orders, not just bob_smith. I'll add the new code.